# How to scan document using desktop scanner and send to SharePoint document using Power Apps and Power Automate

Tags: power-automate, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to implement a requirement where documents are going to be scanned using physical scanner and save in a SharePoint document or List using Power using Power Apps (Canvas App), Power Automate or both.

Comment: Do you want to initiate scanning commands too, from PowerApps only?

Comment: Yes please. But I am not sure PowerApps can handle that

Comment: Not sure about the exact scanning part, but you can click photos and upload them. This might resolve your problem https://youtu.be/iW9dpDntKrY?si=ClnyLpghkVFsgsyQ